# Why does this simple websocket code throw when the client disconnects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I'm writing some simple web socket code based on [these docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html). The server is expected to listen for web sockets and just respond to `ping` messages with `pong`.

I'm running on Python3 and the server code looks like this:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from jsonrpcserver.aio import methods
from jsonrpcserver.response import NotificationResponse

@methods.add
async def ping():
    return 'pong'

async def accept_connection(websocket, path):
    async for request in websocket:
        response = await methods.dispatch(request)
        if not response.is_notification:
            await websocket.send(str(response))

start_server = websockets.serve(accept_connection, 'localhost', 5000)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The client is in Dart and just calls `ping` twice then closes the connection. The output from the server gets this error when the client disconnects:

```
Dannys-MacBook:pythonws danny$ python3 server.py 
--> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"ping","id":0}
<-- {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": "pong", "id": 0}
--> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"ping","id":1}
<-- {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": "pong", "id": 1}
Error in connection handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 152, in handler
    yield from self.ws_handler(self, path)
  File "server.py", line 11, in accept_connection
    async for request in websocket:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/py36/protocol.py", line 15, in __aiter__
    yield await self.recv()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 350, in recv
    yield from self.ensure_open()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 512, in ensure_open
    self.close_code, self.close_reason) from self.transfer_data_exc
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1005 (no status code [internal]), no reason
```

According to the docs linked above:

> Iteration terminates when the client disconnects.

This leads me to believe it should just exit the `async for` loop and not throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/websockets-6.0/autoapi/protocol/index.html

> The iterator yields incoming messages. It exits normally when the connection is closed with the status code 1000 (OK) or 1001 (going away). It raises a ConnectionClosed exception when the connection is closed with any other status code.

Closing with a 1000 status from the client prevents the exception.